# Is there a way to change the contents of a ComboBoxTableCell depending on the row and column that is being edited?

Tags: java, javafx

I am using a JavaFX tableview that has 5 columns (Data Type of Column): Task Id (int), Task Name (String), Task Description (String), Status (String) and Remark (String). Now, I am loading the data from a database that has the same columns and what I'm trying to do is when the user clicks on the task status column in the software the column cell changes to a Combobox (String) but the list of statuses that are displayed in the Combobox should be different depending on the selected item that the user is trying to edit (aka the status of the task)

I have tried creating a new cellFactory in the OnEdit of the column and I have also tried to override the update item method and using a boolean variable I would set whether to set the graphic to a Combobox or not

```
 myStatusColumn.setOnEditStart(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Task, String>>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Task, String> event) {
            try {
                dataBeingEdited = true;
                Task task =  myTasksTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                statuses = Login.dbHandler.getStatuses(task.getTaskTypeID());
                myStatusColumn.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Task, String>, TableCell<Task, String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public TableCell<Task, String> call(TableColumn<Task, String> param) {
                        return new TableCell<Task,String>(){
                            @Override
                            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                                if(empty)
                                    setGraphic(null);
                                else
                                {
                                    if(dataBeingEdited)
                                    {
                                        ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>(statuses);
                                        setGraphic(comboBox);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        };
                    }
                });
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
```

I expect the output to be a Combobox when I double click on the status column but I am not getting a Combobox to appear and when I get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so far I have not found a way to directly use the ComboBoxTableCell class but what I did is redesigned my own using the CellFactory. What I did was before returning the Cell created in the CellFactory I set an onMouseClickedListner that will check for a double click and when the user double clicks I would get the selected item from the table and set the graphic to be a Combobox with values that depend on the row selected and the column clicked 
and then I set an onKeyPressedListener that will change the item selected and then refresh the table and update the database

```
myStatusColumn.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Task, String>, TableCell<Task, String>>() {
        @Override
        public TableCell<Task, String> call(TableColumn<Task, String> param) {
            ComboBox<String> box = new ComboBox<>();
            TableCell<Task, String> cell = new TableCell<Task, String>() {

                @Override
                protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                    if (empty)
                        setGraphic(null);
                    else {
                            setEditable(false);
                            setText(item);
                    }
                }
            };
            cell.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                    if(event.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY))
                    {
                         Task task = myTasksTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                        if(task!=null)
                            box.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(task.getStatuses()));
                        cell.setEditable(true);
                    }
                    if(event.getClickCount()==2 && cell.isEditable() ) {
                        box.getSelectionModel().select(0);
                        cell.setText(null);
                        cell.setGraphic(box);
                    }

                }
            });

            cell.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                    if(event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER))
                    {
                        try {
                            TaskLog taskLog = (TaskLog) myTasksTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                            if(taskLog != null) {
                                taskLog.setStatues(box.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
                                taskLog.setStatuesID(Login.dbHandler.getStatusID(taskLog.getStatues()));
                                System.out.println(taskLog.getStatues());
                                Login.dbHandler.addNewTaskLog(taskLog);
                                cell.setEditable(false);
                                myTasksTable.refresh();
                            }
                        } catch (SQLException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            return cell;
        }
    });
```